# How to create a bean after ServletContext initialized in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I have a bean, which implements ServletContextAware and BeanFactoryPostProcessor interfaces. I need this this bean register into the applicationContext after the ServletContext finished initialization, because I use some parameters in the servletContext to init this bean.

I am using the Spring Boot, the bean name is SpringBeanProcessorServletAware. I have add it into a configuration bean.

```
@Bean
public static SpringBeanProcessorServletAware springBeanProcessor() {
    SpringBeanProcessorServletAware p = new SpringBeanProcessorServletAware();
    return p;
}
```

My issue is that the bean is created before my container set **servletContext** to it. Then I can't get the parameters from the **servletContext**. How to control that the bean must be created after my **servletContext** has been created completely?